# How to disable the multi tenant feature for a GCP project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-identity

I have enabled the multi-tenancy feature for my firebase project in the GCP console following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-quickstart) but now there's no way to disable it back.

Will this affect any of project's behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Public Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-quickstart), currently there is nothing mentioned about how to disable multi-tenancy , however Google Support is aware of the issue and working on it. There will be some update in near future but currently it's not possible in UI or SDKs.

**Will this affect any of the project's behaviour?**

As per [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/dev-workflows/general-best-practices#avoiding-multi-tenancy) , multi-tenancy is not recommended for the Firebase Projects as mentioned with a reason :

> Multi-tenancy can lead to serious configuration and data privacy
> concerns, including unintended issues with analytics aggregation,
> shared authentication, overly-complex database structures, and
> difficulties with security rules.
>
> Generally, if a set of apps don't
> share the same data and configurations, strongly consider registering
> each app with a different Firebase project.
>
> For example, if you
> develop a white-label application, each independently labeled app
> should have its own Firebase project, and the iOS and Android versions
> of that label should be in the same Firebase project. Each
> independently labeled app shouldn't (for privacy reasons) share data
> with the others.

To get more information related to the Firebase Authentication, you can refer to the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth).

If you want to continue in a multi tenant project below are some points which may help you perform certain [activities on a multi tenant](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#user-actions).

> There are situations, however, where you want users to be manually or
> programmatically created by an administrator, either using the Admin
> SDK or Firebase console. In these cases, you can disable user actions
> from the Firebase Authentication Settings page, which prevents account
> creation and deletion by end-users. If you are using multi-tenancy,
> you will need to make an HTTP request to disable these features on a
> per-tenant basis.

You can also [Manage Identity Platform tenants programmatically](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-managing-tenants) by User management,Identity verification,Import users,Access control with custom claims,User session management,Email action links,Tenant management by Create, list, get, update, delete tenants for a specific Identity Platform project , Manage OIDC and SAML providers on tenants.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/getConfig to get the config and after updating configuration for multitenancy repost it to https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/updateConfig

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-quickstart#disabling_multi-tenancy